# Label not getting printed to ios simulator objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview

I can't seem to print my second UILabel , however the first one gets printed. Any help is appreciated.

I am trying to print the yellow label on top of the blue uiview , like i have successfully done with the red label.

here is my code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:  (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(10, 30, 100, 100);

UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
UILabel *myLabel2= [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];


myLabel=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 100)];
myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
myLabel.text = @"Hello";

myLabel2=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,300,100,100)];
myLabel2.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
myLabel2.text=@"World!";


UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1, 1, 500, 500)];
UIView *myView1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65,50,200,200)];
UIView *myView2= [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65,260,200,200)];

myView1.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
myView.backgroundColor=[UIColor cyanColor];
myView2.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];



[myView addSubview:myView1];
[myView addSubview:myView2];
[myView2 addSubview:myLabel2];
[myView1 addSubview:myLabel];
[self.window addSubview:myView];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

thanks for any help.

Comment: Ok, my layout skills are more InterfaceBuilder than direct code layout, but putting a label at (50,300) inside a view that's 200*200 pixels does not look right to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"Actually your label is getting drawn outside the view area of myView2."**
width and height of myView2 is 200,200.
myLabel2 to has y position of 300 which is larger that its superView(myView2)'s height.
:).
myLabel2 is drawn outside myView2's frame. Always y position of a view is taken relative to its superview.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
myLabel2=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,300,100,100)];
```

to

```
myLabel2=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,30,100,100)];
```

Reason is that your `label2` is going outside your view

Hope this helps you..